# Access Children in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

We want to write a little tab component in Angular.

I wrote a component like this:

```
<portal-flex-grid-tab-bar>
  <portal-flex-grid-tab TabName="Apotheke" TabIdentifier="Apotheke"  TabSelected="true" (TabClicked)="OnTabClick(0)"></portal-flex-grid-tab>
  <portal-flex-grid-tab TabName="Bundesland" TabIdentifier="Bundesland"  (TabClicked)="OnTabClick(1)"></portal-flex-grid-tab>
  <portal-flex-grid-tab TabName="ARZ Einzugsgebiet" TabIdentifier="ARZ"  (TabClicked)="OnTabClick(2)"></portal-flex-grid-tab>
</portal-flex-grid-tab-bar>
```

We want to offer the Tab Bar and clicked event which returns the identifier of the clicked tab. If a tab is clicked (selected) we want to deselect the other tabs.

To achieve this goal, we need a way for the parent to talk with his children components and the other way around we need the tabs to send an event to the tab bar. How can we achieve this goal? We would be glad for any ideas as we are starters in Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you shouldn't "talk to" child components, but if you have to, use @ContentChild directive - https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChild

In your case you can control children selection in parent component, e.g. with property `selectedTab`.
So in parent component in you ts:

```
public selectedTab: 0;
public onTabSelected(value: number): void {
    this.selectedTab = value;
}
```

and in parent component in html:

```
<section>
    <app-child-tab isSelected="selectedTab === 0" (tabClicked)="onTabSelected(0)">
    </app-child-tab>
    <app-child-tab isSelected="selectedTab === 1" (tabClicked)="onTabSelected(1)">
    </app-child-tab>
</section>
```

In you child component you have to add EventEmitter:

```
export class ChildComponent {
    @Output() tabClicked: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter();

    public click(): void {
        this.tabClicked.emit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most common way for parent and child to communicate is via a shared service, you have the parent provide the service in it's providers array and then the same instance of the service will be dependency injected into all the child components.

The second method is for the child component the ask for the instance of the parent component in it's dependency list of it's constructor.

Either way you expose methods from either the service or the parent component and observables, usually a behavior subject that can be subscribed to.

If you don't know what I mean by observables or behavior subjects then you are not ready to be learning Angular just yet. If so pause you Angular journey for a day or two and come back after you have a sound understanding of the fundamentals of RxJs as Angular is heavily built upon RxJs. Go read up on Subjects, Behavior Subjects and the RxJs operators.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I know RxJS, Observables, Subjects etc. so far ;)